# fs.writeFile is not a function in angular2+electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, filestream

I have electron + angular2 project.

I need to create file and save it locally after user registers.

In my register.component.ts file I'm trying to use

```
        import fs = require('fs');
        ...
        fs.writeFile(filename, content, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            alert("An error ocurred creating the file " + err.message)
        }

        alert("The file has been succesfully saved");
    });
```

I've installed node types and added

```
    node: {
    fs: "empty"
    },
```

To webpack.common.js file.

Now I'm getting

> ERROR TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function

Any ideas what might cause that?

Comment: Is your `target` also `node`?

Comment: @H.B. Mind explaining your question? :(

Comment: The webpack config has a property called `"target"` which has to be `"node"`. In addition you probably also need `"moduleResultion"` in the `tsconfig.json` to be `"node"`.

Comment: I have not used something like `<package>: empty`, in most cases i just declared externals via [`webpack-node-externals`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).

Comment: @H.B.   Found it, currently it is  "target": "es5". ModuleResolution is node tho. I will change it to node

Comment: @H.B. just found out I can't change it to "node", values are "es3", "es5", "es6" and so on

Comment: That is the tsconfig target. I was talking about the [webpack target](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/). Different thing.

Comment: @H.B. there is no such property "target" in my webpack. Should I add it like this? 


        target: {
            target: 'node'
        },

Comment: Don't double it, it's just `"target": "node"`, see the linked page and other official docs.

Comment: @H.B. Adding target: 'node' or target: "node" shows me 


`app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at app.js:1`

Comment: That could be problem with the `module` in the `tsconfig`. Not sure...

Comment: "module": "commonjs",

Comment: That should be fine, i think.

Comment: Google the error, you'll probably find something useful.

Comment: I'm trying, with no luck. Removing module property didn't solve anything. And before adding "target" property code was running fine

Comment: Apparently there can be an electron specific targets as well. See [this boilerplate project](https://github.com/colinskow/angular-electron-dream-starter) for example. In particular [this config](https://github.com/colinskow/angular-electron-dream-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.electron.js).

Comment: It also uses the node externals i mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I might have to download all project and start from 0:)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `window.require('fs')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `const fs = require('fs');` at the top of your file after the `imports` section.